# Convergence of subsequences and adherent values

Tags: general-topology, analysis, convergence-divergence

if $(x_{n_k})$ is a  subsequence of $(x_n)$ which converges to $l$ in a topological space $E$.

How to prove that $l$ is an adherent value of $(x_n)$ ?

I try this:

Let $V$ an open set which contains $l$, the objective is to prove that $\left|\{n\mid x_n \in V\}\right| =+\infty$ .

as $l$ is a limit of $(x_{n_k})$ that is : $$\exists k_0, : \forall k\geq k_0: x_{n_k}\in V$$

I don't know how to continue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re done, aren’t you?

$\{n_k\mid k \ge k_0\}$ is infinite (that's what it means to be a subsequence: it's an injectively indexed cofinal subset of $\mathbb{N}$, hence infinite) and this set is a subset of $\{n \mid x_n \in V\}$, so the latter set is infinite too.

---

Moreover, if $p$ is a point with a countable local base, say $U_n, n \in \omega$, we can show that if $p$ is an adherent point of $(x_n)$, (so that for all open $O \ni p$ we have $N(O):= \{n: x_n \in O\}$ infinite) then there is a convergent subsequence of $(x_n)$ converging to $p$:

Pick $n_0 = \min(N(U_0))$ which is well-defined.
Next pick $n_1 = \min(N(U_0 \cap U_1)\setminus \{0,1,\ldots,n_0\}$, the first index larger than $n_0$ with value in both $U_0$ and $U_1$ (a finite intersection of neighbourhoods of $p$ is still one and so the corresponding $N$-set is infinite, so has points beyond any limit.

Continuing recursively, define $n_{k+1}= \min(N(\bigcap_{i=0}^k U_i) \setminus \{1,\ldots, n_k\}$ and so we get a subsequence $n_k$ (chosen strictly increasingly from the index set) so that for all $m$, $x_{n_m}$ is in all $U_i$ with $i \le m$. It's easy to check that this implies $x_{n_k} \to p$, using that the $U_n$ form a local base at $p$.

Comment: that's all ??, thank you

Comment: @Vrouvrou I think so. Shoot it down if you’re not convinced.

Comment: the inverse if $l$ is an adherent value of $(x_n)$ where $l$ has a countable family of neighborhoods $\{V_k\}$, then there exists a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ which converge to $l$.

Comment: from the countable system of neighborhoods, if I let $V$ a neighborhood, then there exists $n_0$ such that $V_{n_0}\subset V$, so $|\{n, x_n\in V_{n_0}\}|=+\infty$, how to continue to get the subsequence $x_{n_k}$ ?

Comment: have you an idea please?

Comment: @Vrouvrou I added the argument you asked for.

Comment: please why the minimum exists?

Comment: @Vrouvrou well-order, any non-empty subset of $\mathbb{N}=\omega$ has a minimum. Here all sets are infinite, so certainly non-empty...

Comment: by N you mean the number of elements?

Comment: @Vrouvrou I defined $N(O)$ for $O$ open in the second paragraph. It's an infinite set of indices from $\omega$.

Comment: please why you don't take $n_0=\min(N(U_0))$?

Comment: @Vrouvrou I actually meant to; typo..

Comment: I think that the sequence converge from the construction no? as we delete a finite set of index?

Comment: @Vrouvrou you do need the local base. Try it. Plus the fact that  $x_{n_k} \in U_k$, and so are *all* $x_{n_m}$ with $m > k$. So we get tails inside open sets for free.

Comment: what do you mean by local base?

Comment: @Vrouvrou local base of neighbourhoods, we assumed the adherent point had a countable local base.

Comment: i say in the proof that  the intersection of U is a neighbourhood of l and it contains all $x_{n_k}$ from $n_k$